# Deleted (via flag) posts from users still can leave offensive remnants

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, community-user, offensive

Whee! The proper number of offensive flags and the post is gone.  That is great.

There are still some remnants left though.  In particular, that 'modified' bit on the front page.

> [image: Front page after some offensive]

Its one thing for it to be "yea, there's a naughty word in a deleted post that only 10k+ can see."  It's quite another for it to be "hey, naughty words on the front page."

The proposal:  When a post is deleted via rude/offensive flags, have Community do its 'bump' thing it does with posts that have no up voted answers to the post.  This way you get "modified 1m ago Community♦" there instead.

We really don't need to encourage people to have a mark that remains, well, until someone else modifies the question sitting around on the site.

Comment: the only time this is really an issue is with an offensive user name.  And usually that is unrelated to an offensive post.  Is there really a benefit to thus?

Comment: @psubsee2003 if there is a rude/offensive post the likelihood of a rude/offensive user name goes up. If this was a 'real' user who was trying to contribute, but with an offensive name, the user would likely be flagged and things would have been cleaned up there.  For a new user who creates an account to vandalize, denying them as much attention as possible is likely a good thing.  Rude/offensive doesn't do the account destruction for a new user that spam does (IIRC) - its only a problem with rude and offensive users being rude and offensive with rude and offensive names.

Answer (score 5):

If a user created solely to post spam or offensive posts also has an offensive user name, the correct way to deal with this is to simply delete the user. This would work in your example, the post would be attributed to the community user because the original owner no longer exists.

Of course this requires the involvement of a moderator, but I don't see this as a huge problem.